# How to play a video when param is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-video

I'm using `timesheets.js` to make a SMIL-presentation.

In the JavaScript console I see this:

```
<div id="slide3" class="transition" smil="active">
    <video id="foo" source type="video/mp4" src="foo.mp4">
</div>
```

The parameter: `smil="active"` is either `active` or `done`.

I want to play the `foo.mp4` when `smil="active"`

I've added this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#foo').prop('autoplay', true);
    });
</script>
```

But it plays the video when page is loaded, so when `smil="active"` the video has ended.

How can I fix this?

**Edit:**

This is the js that that fires up the state = "active":

```
var state = "";
  this.isActive = function() { return (state == "active"); };
  this.show  = function() {
    if (state == "active") return;
    state = "active";
    if (0) try {
      consoleLog(domNode.nodeName + "#" + domNode.id + " -- show()");
    } catch(e) {}
    self.setTargetState(state);
    self.dispatchEvent("begin");
    self.addEventListener(endEvents, onendListener);
    self.removeEventListener(beginEvents, onbeginListener);
    //if (self.parentNode.timeContainer == "excl") consoleLog("show");
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the attribute is equal to active before playing:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if($('#slide3').attr('smil') == 'active') {
     $('#foo').prop('autoplay', true);
  }
  else {
     $('#foo').prop('autoplay', false);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It didn't help though.. :/ It doesn't change the prop to autoplay

Comment: @HundkartanJonas It does work judging from your code above. You need to provide me more code or a jsFiddle - how are you changing the attribute?

Comment: Absolutely!
Link here: [link]http://centrumkanalen.se/btv/timesheets/demo/slideshow2.html

Comment: @HundkartanJonas How are you actually changing the smil attribute in jQuery? All you have to do is wrap my if/else statement inside whatever event causes the change of value and it'll work.

Comment: @HundkartanJonas Just place `$('#foo').prop('autoplay', true);` inside your `if state == active` statement, and make an `else state == done` and put `$('#foo').prop('autoplay', false);` inside that...

Comment: This just set the autoplay for the video, so when the video is active, it has been played already

Comment: Yes but when I place your code in the .js, the video plays (because the state is active). I want the video to play when the state for #slide3 is active

Comment: @HundkartanJonas In that case the code I've already posted checks for that, now like I already said - wrap that code inside whatever event occurs to give #slide3 that attribute and it will work.

Comment: @HundkartanJonas Please let me know when you've done that, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your patients :) I didn't solve it I'm afraid. Please see this [link]http://jsfiddle.net/gQeVR/4/

Comment: I want to do like this: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285052/anythingslider-html-5-video-autoplay     but in this slideshow